# Efficient Way to Integrate Project as a Package?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have two independently developed Android projects (with own activities etc.), tested and working independently.

One project is now supposed to be launching (via Intent) the second project.

I could have kept it that way, but when distributing it via the Android Market, it will necessitate 2 APKs, 2 icons, etc. which could be very confusing to the end user.

So I would like to integrate the second project into the first one, while keeping it as a **separate package**.

A straightforward approach for doing this is to manually create an empty package, then copy over all files, one by one, from the second project. Tedious.

Is there a built-in shortcut in Eclipse (or ADT) to do this, similar to the `File > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can make your second project as a `Library Project` by right clicking on it and in the Android tab check `isLibrary`. And then in your first project, you link the one that you made a library by right clicking again and under the Android tab, Libraries, click Add and point to your `Library Project`. You could also have a look at [Managing Projects from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

If this does not work (but I really should), you can simply just right click on your packages, then select `Copy` and go to your first project, and just right click -> `Paste`. This also worked for me.

Comment: Thanks +1. Making the second project a Library project (as you suggested) compiles and build but fails in runtime with `ActivityNotFoundException` (no activity found to handle Intent). This doesn't happen if I keep the two project two independent applications. Any idea why?

Comment: To clarify, the only difference between when it works and it doesn't work is checking `isLibrary` and adding it as a Library to the calling project. That is, no changes whatsoever in the code or any of the XML files. What else do I need to change to make this migration work?

Comment: I got an idea: If `startActivity` with new `Intent(Context, class)` is only applicable if the activity is within the same application, then perhaps the opposite is true, too? i.e. `Intent("com.test.application")` is only applicable if the activity is NOT within the same application?

Comment: I think you are forgetting to add the `Activities` declarations in the  `Manifest.xml`